# Opencl on ARM - Unable to retrieve platform id

Tags: arm, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, mali

I am running open cl on a linux machine with ARM processor and Mali GPU remotely. But it is giving an error something like "Unknown error: cannot retrieve platform id" at clGetPlatformIDs().

I tried both

```
cl_uint numPlatforms;   //the NO. of platforms
cl_platform_id platform = NULL; //the chosen platform
cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
```

and

```
cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, &numPlatforms);
```

but for both, I am getting the same error. The same code is working for me on my personal windows laptop with AMD graphics.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Reason can be simple - OpenCL driver isn't working well. That's why you can't load platforms list. Did you test that ARM machine with OpenCL code before?

Comment: no. I am trying for the first time. But apparently this machine was being used by others for running opencl before.

Comment: Usually, this error means that OpenCL driver isn't runnung, as colleting platforms list is the 1st step. What kind of remote connection do you use? Is it just SSH session, or VNC/RDP ?

Comment: i am using putty to connect to the linux machine from my windows machine

Comment: what do you have in /etc/OpenCL/vendors on target machine?

Answer (score 0):

By arm linux machine you mean arm chromebook? libOpenCL.so in your machine is only a stub driver. Actual platform implementations are listed in /etc/OpenCL/vendors. You could also have libOpenCL.so without icd support exposing only 1 platform

In any case if its samsung arm chromebook, arm has a detailed setup guide for mali opencl & opengl-es http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/features/graphics-and-compute-development-on-samsung-chromebook/

Comment: yes. it is a samsung arm chromebook. I cannot find /etc/OpenCL folder in the machine. Thanks for the link